# Can you solve 2-sat problem when truth assignments of some variables are determined

Tags: 2-sat

I am trying to find a assignment to satisfy a 2-sat statement. Problem is some of the clauses are `0 or x` or `1 or x`. I think the `1 or x` clauses have no effect on the solution, but the `0 or x` clauses determine the value for x. As I have clauses like `~x or y` the determined value for x results in determining the value for y and so on. Can I solve this problem with Krom's procedure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First set all literals $x$ to $1$ if they appear in a clause $0 \vee x$, and set $\bar x$ to $0$. If that requires you to set some $x$ to both $0$ and $1$, it's unsatisfiable. Iterate this until you don't have to set any more literals to $0$. If you get this far without finding out that the formula is unsatisfiable, remove all clauses that contain a $1$. Now you either have no clauses left - then it's satisfiable - or some 2-CNF formula to which you can apply Krom's algorithm.

Alternatively, remove all clauses $1 \vee x$ and replace all clauses $0 \vee x$ by $(y \vee x) \wedge (\bar y \vee x)$ for a newly introduced variable $y$. You can directly apply Krom's algorithm (or more likely, a linear-time algorithm like that of [Aspvall, Plass, Tarjan](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/CourseWeb/Math268_2007WS/2SAT.pdf)) to the formula you get this way.

Answer (score 7):

Also a similar solution is to define `Zero` and `One` variables and add two extra clauses $ \bar{zero} \vee \bar{zero} $ for value 0 and $ one \vee one $ for value 1. After that we can follow the Krom's algorithm.